# Xamarin out of memory error inside binding library

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

using visual studio xamarin after binding an image-processing library, and imported the .Dll file as reference to my App project. when i pass an image to the library the App crash with this error

> Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 91411212 byte allocation with 2810016 free bytes and 2MB until OOM

it occurs inside the library only when i pass a large image files >2MB. 
i already increased the java max heap size for the project to max (1G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to bypass this issue by passing a scaled-down copy of the image as i don't need to process the image with it's full resolution.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it tells you that it cannot allocate 91411212 bytes. This is quite a lot around 87 MB of uncompressed data.

Seems like either the library is broken or that it is doing something really bad.

Increasing heap-size in the project-properties is only for build time, for when Java runs out of memory or needs more resources. So this does not affect run-time at all.

Which library is this?

Comment: it's Catalano Jar libraries  (super similar to Aforge) i bind it using VS and 
i managed to bypass that error by minimizing the source image to 800 x 800 pxs before passing it to the library ,,